# Google Map View on Non Touch-Screen Phones

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps, trackball

I have implemented Google Map view in my app with a number of custom markers. I am testing in the emulator and everything works fine if I treat the emulator like a touch screen phone - I can click on the custom markers and navigate and move the map properly.

However I don't seem to be able to manipulate the map with the trackball / dpad controls. Can Google Map view be used with the trackball or dpad ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try overriding the `onTrackballEvent(android.view.MotionEvent event)` method in the MapView.